# Creating remote bookmarks while pushing to hgweb server

Tags: mercurial, nginx, bookmarks, hgrc, hgweb

There's a lot of questions about bookmarks but none of them answers my question:

What should I do to allow for creating bookmarks while pushing to my hgweb server?

Here's what I'm getting while trying to push bookmark:

```
$ hg push -B feature1
pushing to http://local_server/hg/Project
searching for changes
no changes found
exporting bookmark feature1
updating bookmark feature1 failed!
```

Is there anything I should put into `.hgrc` or in `hgweb` config?

When bookmarks already exist in remote repo then they are updated, also creating bookmarks by push works on bitbucket so I'm sure it's possible.

**Problem solved:**

In system there were two Mercurial versions installed:

```
/usr/bin/hg == v1.4
/usr/local/bin/hg == v2.2
```

Although `wchich hg` prints `/usr/local/bin/hg` nginx was using `/usr/bin/hg`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the Mercurial on the server support bookmarks? What version is it?

Comment: @Helgi, 2.2. As far as I know it supports bookmarks natively

Comment: Well. I've just tried a `hg push -B mybookmark` against a repo deployed with `hg serve` behind nginx, Mercurial version's 2.0, on Windows. It worked without any problems. I guess the problem lies in the peculiarities of your configuration. Care to update the question?

Comment: Do you have any hooks in use (on the remote and/or your local repo)?

Comment: @ObenSonne, I've got hooks on server but when I remove them it's the same.

Comment: Run your push with `--debug` option. Maybe this provides some insights here.

Comment: @ObenSonne, there's nothing unusual in debug listing. I quess this may be problem with my nginx setup. This question becomes too localized :/

Comment: Are there any clues in your server access/error logs?

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you should really make it as an "answer" and mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

In system there were two Mercurial versions installed:

```
/usr/bin/hg == v1.4
/usr/local/bin/hg == v2.2
```

Although `which hg` shows `/usr/local/bin/hg` nginx was using `/usr/bin/hg`.